# What algebra book to read after Artin's Algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, book-recommendation

Could I directly go to Lang's Algebra? Or should I supplement some gaps by Dummit and Foote?

Comment: Is there a reason you're set on Lang?

Comment: That's because I have seen so many people here recommending that book.

Comment: Try Aluffi's book!

Comment: Lang is pretty dense.  It's not unfeasible, but I'd definitely keep Dummit and Foote handy.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "supplement some gaps"? Perhaps you mean that anytime you don't understand it in Lang, you find it in another source (e.g. D&F). If that's the case, then I can't think of a single situation where this isn't a great idea.

Comment: That's true. I may just read D&F and Lang at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I openly recomend you Hoffman's Algebra. Only if you want solid basis in Algebra!

Comment: This does not appear to be an answer to the question that was asked.